# Method to grab URL hash in Twig or craft.request?

Tags: templating, url

Is there a method or recommended way of grabbing URL hash parameters with Twig?

For example, if my URL is http://mysite.com/my-page#hash, is there a way to grab the hash?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't possible because the `#hash`-part isn't even send to the server. See this question on StackOverflow: [Can PHP read the hash portion of the URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/940905/3589841)

But if you use `?hash=something` instead, these functions will help you: [`getParam()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.request#getParam) and [`getQuery()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.request#getQuery)